# undefined method `delay' for UserMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, delay, delayed-job

I am getting the following error while writing mail notification process asynchronously by using **delay** method.

```
NoMethodError in SampleController#create

undefined method `delay' for UserMailer:Class
```

I have the following code in my controller.

```
UserMailer.delay.idea_author_notification(self,nfication)
```

I have already installed delayed_job gem also started delayed_job by using **jobs:work** rake task.

Shall I need to do some other changes for using delay method for executing mail related code in background ?

Please help me on this asap..

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: after running bundle, have you restarted your server?  You need to do this everytime you add a new gem in your Gemfile.

Comment: did you use `require 'delayed_job'` and restart server and please use `gem "delayed_job",  :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'` in your Gemfile

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.5. So I have tried with delayed_job 2.0.8 version. I have also restarted the server. But still getting issue with delay method.

Comment: Fyi shouldn't it `deliver_idea_author_notification` if it is rails 2.3.5 sure that doenot solve the problem but still

Comment: Please attach your mailer code as well

Answer (score -2):

the method **delay** is not existed for **any action mailer** class. So you can not call that method for the **UserMailer:Class**.

For that you can check all the methods for the mailer class in the rails console. i.e
**UserMailer.methods** 
and to check particular method existed or not, run the following line.

**UserMailer.methods.include?(:delay)** 
The above line returns **false**

OR

if you want to use delayed jobs, please go through the following link in github. It would definitely help you.

[delayed_jobs_for_rails2.x.x](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0)

Comment: this is out of subject. `delay` is added whenever you add the delayed_job gem. That's the point here

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.5. So I have tried with delayed_job 2.0.8 version. I have also restarted the server. But still getting issue with delay method.

Comment: @VentatK the method is not supported directly in ruby but its a part of Object after `delayed_job` gem is used

Comment: yes, that is the case over here. if we use the delayed_job gem, we can call the delay method.

Comment: if that is rails-2.3.5, we need to add this into the config.

Comment: Please go through the link: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0

Comment: @VenkatK Add what ? `delay` method is the part of the object check [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v2.0/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L17) and [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v2.0/lib/delayed_job.rb#L10)

Comment: I have followed as per the above github link only. But still getting issue with delay method. Is there any bug with delayed_job 2.0.8 version gem?

Comment: Try to run it like this UserMailer.idea_author_notification(self,nfication).delay

Comment: @techvineet I dont think that will work because it like running the code and then asking it to `delay`

Comment: @Viren there is no harm in trying that, this code sometimes works for me though

Comment: @techvineet the idea of solution is to push thing in background if he as to do that what harm in this `UserMailer.idea_author_notification(self,nfication)` surely it will do the same thing

Comment: Hi, I have resolved this issue. For this I have added some code into config/initializers. Now the mail related code executing successfully in background job, but we are unable to get mail.